# Probability problem with sets

Tags: probability

Tv company receives 90 job application. Information about applicants:

```
--------------------------------------------
     | have bachelor | dont have bachelor |
     |     (B)       |     (B) negation   |
---------------------------------------------
exp  |     18        |          9         |
(D)  |               |                    |
---------------------------------------------
no exp |      36     |         27         |
(D)     |            |                    |
negation|------------|--------------------|
```

Calculate probability for: `P(D/B) and P(B neg/ D neg )`

answers:  `P(D/B) => 1/3`,  `P(B neg/ D neg ) => 3/7`

I tried to do this->

D/B = D - DnB = 18+9 - 18 = 9

P(D/B) = 9/90 = 1/10 (wrong)

and

D/B = B - BnD = 54 - 18 = 36

P(D/B) = 36/90 = 4/10 (wrong)

I have no idea where I am wrong. How to figure out the answer?

Comment: The question is of conditional probability. You should read a bit about it (Bayes theorem atleast) to get a better understanding of the question. (PS : The answers 1/3 and 3/7 are correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Calculating P(D|B)**

P(D|B): Probability, that a applicant has already experiences- given he/she has a Bachelor. You have $54(=18+36)$ applicants having a Bachelor. Now you read off the number of the applicants with a bachelor and experiences. The number is 18.

Thus $P(D|B)=\frac{P(D \cap B)}{P(b)}=\frac{18}{54}=\frac{1}{3}$

The base is here all the applicants, who have a Bachelor. Now you calculate/read off, how many of them has experiences. If you have already a contingency table, then it is quiet easy.